# Detecting the other peer is down in TCP

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am building an APP over TCP and to detect the other end is down, I need to implement a heartbeat mechanism where the client keeps sending pseudo ping packets. I did some testing and saw that when the other end is down, the number of bytes read is 0.

So I can I not so something like this?:

```
If  FD is set, then 
read from fd
if read bytes is 0 then
Assume socket is closed, close fd and do a reconnect.
```

This is working for me so I don't understand the need for having a keep alive, I have the same logic for the server and it works for me.

Am I thinking straight?

Comment: Read http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/

Comment: Yes, I know about TCP keepalive, but I am talking about APP heartbeats when I say keepalives

Comment: You may want to call `poll(2)` syscall. But I don't understand your question. If you want some application-level "heartbeat" make it like any other request...

Comment: Imagine you only read from you socket. Then you unplug the network cable of whoever is sending you data. Or you smash it with a sledge hammer. Or some router inbetween catches fire.  How do you detect that the peer is gone ? read() is not going to return 0. read() will never return if you use blocking sockets. No data will appear on that socket. Unless you try to send something on that socket, you'll never know its gone. (Note that there's *many* corner cases in such scenario, some much worse than I described, some much easier, and some where you would get a notification that the peer is gone)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345415/socket-detect-connection-is-lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of read return 0 is that the peer sends FIN. If there is some network issue between you and peer (the network cable is plugged out), how do your application detect it without keepalive? The read will block for a long time (depend on your OS environment).

Comment: Why can I not use tcp keepalives instead of APP heartbeats..Is not TCP designed to handle that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345415/socket-detect-connection-is-lost
Here they say TCP keepalives cannot be used

Comment: no they don't. They say they should not be used. Not that they can't be used. Ofcourse, the default TCP keepalives are in the order of hours - which is often unsuitable, and most robust applications should have more control over how they detect and respond to outages (which if you use TCP keepalives, you get little control.)